# Jasper Report If Else Condition Expression

Tags: if-statement, jasper-reports

I would like to ask about the if else expression in ireport jasper report. May I know is it possible to have multiple or more parameter in the if else statement?

```
(($P{endDate}.isEmpty()==true || $P{endDate}.equals(""))? "" :
" createDate>='" + $P{startDate} +"'" && " createDate<='" + $P{endDate} +"'")
```

Based on the code above, there are not allowed me to use "&&". It prompt out syntax error.
Besides that, May I know any solution to solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you intend your expression to mean?

Comment: my expression is to let user enter the parameter. There might have several parameter to let user enter. User can choose to enter either one or more. And this expression is to detect what parameter that user enter and decide which action to take.

Comment: Your *else* expression `" createDate>='" + $P{startDate} +"'" && " createDate<='" + $P{endDate} +"'"` tries to apply the `&&` operator (which is applicable only to boolean values) to two `String` arguments. Thus, a syntax error. I don't understand what you want your *else* expression to evaluate to at all, so I cannot tell you how to correct it.

Comment: Also, are you using this expression for a dataset query? If so, what type of dataset are you using? If you are using this expression for a dataset query, I'm afraid you can't use this Java syntax.

Comment: If it's a query, you'll need something like this: http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/how-write-conditional-query-ireport-using-parameters

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it's a query expression your trying to write. You probably would have to do something as follows:

Create a parameter for your dataset. This parameter should not be "prompted" and lets call it DATE_LIMIT_EXPRESSION. You should then set its default value as your expression. For example (if I a get what you meant), this could be your default expression:

```
"1" + 
(($P{startDate}.isEmpty() == false) ? (" AND createDate >= " + $P{startDate}) : "") +
(($P{stopDate}.isEmpty() == false) ? (" AND stopDate <= " + $P{stopDate}) : "")
```

Now, your dataset query should be something like:

```
select 
    ...
where $P!{DATE_LIMIT_EXPRESSION}
```

Just notice the "$P!" syntax. You can find more information about this in the [Jasper Reports' documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/).